# Check if image removed due to tumblr violation

Tags: tumblr

Is there any way to check if an image returned by the Tumblr api was removed due to violations?

At the moment it seems the API returns some URLs which link to something like this:

[image]

It also does not appear the HTTP request to the img itself is redirected, as it returns a 304 code like everything else.

Comment: Interesting question! I am inclined to say there isn't a way of knowing. The API doesn't have the facility and as you mention, the request code is the same.

Comment: Yeah.  I'd hate to have to have to download the image and do an actual comparison using imagemagick or something.  Though it does seem, if you requery the image post, they update it with a content_size.jpg file link, instead of the original one.  (both would show the same violation image).  But the issue here is that, until you requery, it will still get through to the frontend.  It doesn't seem feasible to requery every post every time.